# Open another activity on click of listview an display the text from assets folder

Tags: android

I have create a listview an now want to open an 2nd activity on click from listview item and open the text file from assest folder to the 2nd activity how do i do that ??pls help me with the correct code..

1)this is the java code for my list view

```
package com.example.dell.cap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class basicc extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basicc);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);


    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter =new  ArrayAdapter<String>(basicc.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.basics));


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(basicc.this,Displaytext.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

}
```

2)this is the list view items

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">CAP</string>
<string name="sets_string"><![CDATA[Sets & String]]></string>


<string-array name="basics">
    <item>Accessing an array using pointers.c</item>
    <item>C program for Binary to decimal conversion.c</item>
    <item>C program for decimal to octal converter.c</item>
    <item>C program for hexadecimal to binary conversion.c</item>
    <item>C program to accept an array of 10 elements and swap 3rd element  
 with 4th element using pointers and display the results..c</item>
    <item>C program to accept N numbers sorted in ascending order and to 
search for a given number using binary search..c</item>
    <item>C Program to Accept the Height of a Person &amp; Categorize as 
Taller, Dwarf &amp; Average.c</item>
    <item>C Program to Accept two Integers and Check if they are 
Equal.c</item>
    <item>C Program to Add two Complex Numbers.c</item>v
    <item>C Program to Calculate the Sum of Odd &amp; Even Numbers.c</item>
    <item>C Program to calculate the total execution time of a 
program.c</item>
    <item>C Program to Check if a given Integer is Odd or Even.c</item>


</string-array>
</resources>
```

[this is the 2nd activity on which i want to display the text from assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQtL8.jpg)

[This is the assets folder and text files i want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brxKz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use onItemClickListener.
like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(basicc.this,Displaytext.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
});
```